# Cannot access supervisor web interface on guest machine from host

Tags: virtual-machines, vagrant, supervisord

I set up an ubuntu virtual machine using Vagrant. In my Vagrantfile, I have configured a private network like in the example:

`config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10`

In `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`, I have the lines:

```
[inet_http_server]
port=127.0.0.1:9001
```

When I run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9002`, I can reach the guest machine via my browser from the host machine using `192.168.33.10:9002`.

However, when I try to access `192.168.33.10:9001`, I get no response. When I try to open a python web server on that port, it says that the address is in use. Thus, I guess the supervisor web interface is running but somehow not accessible.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the IP-address from localhost to any:

```
[inet_http_server]
port=*:9001
```

See if that works!